# Flutter: Autocomplete suggestions shows 'instance of object' instead of name

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using AutoComplete widget available flutter show suggestions list but it shows `instance of 'LOTOEmployee'` instead of the names of employees.

where employee list is stored,

```
List<LOTOEmployee> employees = [];
```

code for AutoComplete widget,

```
Autocomplete<LOTOEmployee>(
                           optionsBuilder: (value) {
                                  return employee
                                       .where((e) => e.label.contains(value.text));
                                  },
                              ),
```

what it is showing

[image]

can someone tell me how I can fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why does this happen?*

By default a class in dart output "Instance of " from the `toString` method.

*How do I fix this?*

Override the `toString` method for the `LOTOEmployee` class and return the output value you require.

*For Example:*

```dart
class LOTOEmployee {
    String name;
    @override
    String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: if this answer helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer. So we can help others with the same question on StackOverflow

Comment: It should not depend on the "toString()" method of the class because it would degrade the loose coupling. The "toString()" method of the classes were not meant and should not be used to solve the functionality of a specific component. The component should be able to solve this problem by itself, and in Flutter's autocomplete example, the displayStringForOption property should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

There's a better solution to do this.
Autocomplete has another parameter called "displayStringForOption" which receives the option and outputs a string.

```dart
return Autocomplete(
      optionsBuilder: (value) { ... },
      displayStringForOption: (employee) => employee.label,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

overriding the toString() method is a shorthand solution, but in the results needed to be generated through the more than one fields of the (LOTOEmployee) CLASS, it will be complex to get rid from this.

- Proper Approach:

```
    Autocomplete<LOTOEmployee>(
     optionsBuilder: (value) 
     {
       return employee.where((e) => 
       e.label.contains(value.text)).toList();
     },
     displayStringForOption: (LOTOEmployeebeans beans) => beans.label),
```

- while on optionViewBuilder Side, you need to mention these few things:

```
     optionsViewBuilder:(BuildContext context, Function onSelected, 
     Iterable<LOTOEmployeebeans> options) {

     // MaterialApp/Widgets/ListTile goes here.
     // You can even use the other fields of the class here ( 
     options.emplyeeSalary )

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                  Autocomplete<Category>(
                      optionsBuilder:
                          (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) async {
                        
                        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                          return const Iterable<Category>.empty();
                        }
                        return await controller.getCategories();
                      },
                      onSelected: (Category selection) {
                        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
                      },
                      optionsViewBuilder: (context,
                          Function(Category) onSelected,
                          Iterable<Category> options) {
                        return Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Material(
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 200,
                              width: 200,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                itemCount: options.length,
                                itemBuilder:
                                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  final option = options.elementAt(index);
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      onSelected(option);
                                    },
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text(option.name!),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

You can use `optionsViewBuilder` to build the item display.